# I don't know why warning

Tags: c, warnings

```
void string_copy(char *a,char *b){
    for(int i = 0,n = strlen(a);i <= n;i++){
    *(a+i) = *(b+i);
    }
}
typedef char* string;
string p1 = "";
string p2 = "Hello World";
string_copy(&p1,&p2);
printf("%s",p1);
```

Error log:

```
    main.c:20:17: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘string_copy’ from incompatible pointer         type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
       20 |     string_copy(&p1,&p2);
      |                 ^~~
      |                 |
      |                 char **
    In file included from main.c:2:
    lglib.h:50:24: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
   50 | void string_copy(char *a,char *b);
      |                  ~~~~~~^
    main.c:20:21: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘string_copy’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   20 |     string_copy(&p1,&p2);
      |                     ^~~
      |                     |
      |                     char **
    In file included from main.c:2:
    lglib.h:50:32: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
   50 | void string_copy(char *a,char *b);
      |
```

Comment: `&p` is taking address of `p`, therefore having the type of `char**`, while the function is expecting `char*`. But regardless, you can't copy anything into `p1` because it is 1) A pointer to a read-only string literal. 2) It is shorter than the string being copied.

Comment: OT: Don't try to create your own "string" type with `typedef char* string`, it only adds confusion.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I think it's from CS50.

Comment: I'm trying to make a header file like cs50 and add some content, but I don't know why it's warning, I just learned C for a week.

Comment: @ZhenzheGao if you are not required to use weird stuff like the infamous cs50 header, then don't try to make your own. Their pseudo `string` type is a terrible idea.

Comment: @ZhenzheGao It's not possible to understand how C works if you hide the details with abominations like CS50's `typedef char* string` - which is why you're having problems with this.  C can be difficult enough - hiding what's actually going on with your code just makes it harder.

Comment: You could get rid of this warning by calling your function like `string_copy(p1, p2);`, but this does not fix the undefined behavior when you try to overwrite the string literal `""`. I suggest to use `a[i]` instead of `*(a+i)` because the first form is easier to read. To have a string that can be written to, you need a `char` *array* with enough space for the bytes of the string plus a trailing `'\0'`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `char*` in C instead of a custom typedef called "string". If you really want to use "string" then you should check out the C++ [std::string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) STL container instead of rewring the C language. Also, picking better names than "a" and "b" makes it more readable. Here, "dest" is the destination and "src" is the source. You are copying from the source, so `strlen(a or dest)` was wrong and should be `strlen(src)`. The reason why you had a warning is because `&p1` is a `char**` since you took the address of the `char*`.

```
void string_copy(char *dest, char *src) {
    for (int i = 0, l = strlen(src); i <= l; i++) {
        dest[i] = src[i];
    }
}
char *p1 = malloc(20);    // must allocate memory or else can't change
char *p2 = "Hello World"; // like this read only string for example
string_copy(p1, p2);      // p1, not &p1
printf("%s", p1);
```

If you want to make things a lot easier, you can use [strcpy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) but be aware that there is no [bounds checking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounds_checking).

```
char *p1 = malloc(20);    // must allocate memory or else can't change
char *p2 = "Hello World"; // like this read only string for example
strcpy(p1, p2);      // p1, not &p1
printf("%s", p1);
```